# What comes with the AWS Lambda event and context

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I've got AWS Lambda written in Ruby 2.7 and the Lambda is setup based on `templates.yml`. Since I'm not able to use debugger on AWS Lambda which is run locally (AWS SAM gives me an error: Ruby 2.7 is not supported at the moment - [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-using-debugging.html)) I also can't check what's coming inside Event and Context.

My lambda uses the Gateway API, and I'm wondering what I should do to pull the entire payload (I assume it's in the body of the request) from the request that comes in at `POST /quizzes`, which looks like the following:

```
{
    "quiz":
    {
        "first_name": "john",
        "last_name": "doe",
        "ssn": "1234",
        "address":
        {
            "line1": "4444 NW ANYSTREET AVE",
            "city": "anytown",
            "state": "FL",
            "zip_code": "33333"
        },
        "dob":
        {
            "day": 25,
            "month": 12,
            "year": 2000
        }
    }
}
```

From the entire Lambda Event I want to fetch and pass only the body that is attached to the request. In other words, what does the event look like with this type of request body?

Comment: @luk2302 Logs are in CloudWatch

Comment: Sorry, misread the first sentences - the easiest way to get going is to just log the entire event and just inspect the data and go from there.

Comment: Is it possible to do so locally without deploying anything to AWS?

Comment: I just figure out that the easiest way is just to pass the `event` to the lambda response like `{ statusCode: 200, body: { message: event }.to_json }`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know what an event in lambda looks like, you can use AWS SAM to generate the body of a fake event using the [`sam local generate-event` command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-local-generate-event.html).